# KVM: isolation between different NAT networks

Tags: networking, kvm, nat

I'm trying to setup multiple NAT networks in KVM that are isolated from each other and can't get it work.
I face a behaviour that I can't explain, and I would like some clarification about it.

If I setup 3 NAT networks in the IP range 192.168.122.0/24, 192.168.123.0/24 and 192.168.124.0/24, and start them in THAT order, VMs in 122 will not be able to ping either VMs in 123 or 124 (this is the behaviour I want), VMs in 123 will be able to ping 122 but not 124, and VMs in 124 will ping 122 and 123.

Start order seems important, because it will implies the iptables rules order, which I thing is the reason of the behaviour.

I have read in this [doc](https://wiki.libvirt.org/page/TaskNATSetupVirtManager):

> In this step, you choose a range of IP addresses to use inside this virtual network. They will be visible to all guests using this virtual network, but won't be seen outside of it due to the NAT.

and in this [tutorial](https://fabianlee.org/2019/05/26/kvm-creating-a-guest-vm-on-a-nat-network/):

> Although the Host OS and public networks cannot initiate connections back to guests in the NAT network, take note that KVM guests in other NAT do have the ability to reach it.

information that seems contradictory.

I'd like to understand the actual behaviour, and to know if there is a way to achieve what I want.

Edit: The full setup is a bit complicated because it involves a GNS3 layer.

**What I have tried:**

1. Create different Virtual NAT Network through `virt-manager` on different IP range. For instance the result of `virsh net-dumpxml` on two of those network are :

```
# Note : This one is the default one
<network>
  <name>default</name>
  <uuid>5506b439-c3f6-4d8a-b901-66736c18c976</uuid>
  <forward mode='nat'>
    <nat>
      <port start='1024' end='65535'/>
    </nat>
  </forward>
  <bridge name='virbr0' stp='on' delay='0'/>
  <mac address='52:54:00:9c:bf:07'/>
  <ip address='192.168.122.1' netmask='255.255.255.0'>
    <dhcp>
      <range start='192.168.122.2' end='192.168.122.254'/>
    </dhcp>
  </ip>
</network>
```

```
# Note : This one is one I created through virt-manager
<network>
  <name>nat-network1</name>
  <uuid>dca96cc1-b4bd-44ac-b1b9-9f581219fa94</uuid>
  <forward mode='nat'>
    <nat>
      <port start='1024' end='65535'/>
    </nat>
  </forward>
  <bridge name='virbr1' stp='on' delay='0'/>
  <mac address='52:54:00:2e:7d:d5'/>
  <domain name='defaul1'/>
  <ip address='192.168.123.1' netmask='255.255.255.0'>
    <dhcp>
      <range start='192.168.123.2' end='192.168.123.254'/>
    </dhcp>
  </ip>
</network>
```

2. Use a special interface in GNS3 (the "Cloud" one) that allows to link VMs to those NAT Virtual Network. I have linked for instance VM1 to `default` and VM2 to `nat-network1`. Both VM take an IP through DHCP in the range I have defined, both have an access to Internet.

**What I expected:** I expected that VM that are setup to use different NAT Network would not be able to communicate. It appears it is not the case, in the way I explained at the beggining.

Comment: Hello and welcome to UL.SE! If you show us  a little more of your work's technical details, we may be able to help you. What did you try so far? What does your current setup do? Why is this not what you intented your setup to do?

Comment: Hello, I have just updated my answer. I tried to explain what I have done in a better way, but do not hesitate to ask for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the tutorial you posted it mentions:

> If you do not set the “dev” attribute to either the physical network
>   device or bridge, then you will get unexpected behavior because it may
>   take shortcuts and forward traffic directly from one KVM network to
>   another using internal interfaces.

This seems to be what would cause your issue.

change:

```
  <forward mode='nat'>
```

to:

```
  <forward mode='nat' dev='<network interface example: eth0>' >
```

I tested this out it makes the iptables rules work.